# Eliminate clicks/pops from Play function

Tags: sound

When using the [`Play`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Play.html) function with a simple [`Sin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) wave, the audio clicks/pops at the beginning and end of the audio sample.  How can I make a quick ~20 millisecond fade in as it starts to play and another ~20 ms fade out at the end to eliminate the clicks/pops? If possible, I'd rather not use [`CosineWindow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CosineWindow.html) as it takes too long to fade in/out.  Thank you!

```
Play[Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Can't you use audiofade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Play[
 LogisticSigmoid[(5 t)/0.2 - 5]
  LogisticSigmoid[(5 (2 - t))/0.2 - 5]
  Sin[440 2 Pi t]
 , {t, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]